# Groovy XmlSlurper cannot get lang attribute with default namespace

Tags: xml, groovy

I have the following xml

```
<group xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3">
    <item>
        <text xml:lang="en">Mild</text>
        <text xml:lang="fr">Legere</text>
    </item>
<group>
```

I want to get all the "en" string from the xml.
I am parsing it with the following groovy code

```
def doc = new XmlSlurper().parse(inputstream).declareNamespace(xmlns:'http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3')

List<String> text = []
def s = doc.item.find{ it@":lang" = "en"}.each {
    text.add(it.text())
}

println text
```

The problem is it seams to be ignoring the attribute. I registered the default namespace, i've tried combinations of xml:lang, :lang, lang in the find closure but no joy.

Does any body know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `xml` prefix always refers to the namespace `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` - this is fixed [in the namespaces specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#xmlReserved) and does not need to be declared in an XML document.

So try

```
def doc = new XmlSlurper().parse(inputstream).declareNamespace(
   xml:'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace')
```

and then `xml:lang` should work as you expect.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it did not work. If I call attributes().size() on the text node I get 1 but when I do a getAt(0) it returns null. I've also tried to parse with XmlParser and it gives the same result.